# Character array returns every 4th character when iterated through

Tags: c, tcp

I am writing a Client that connects to an Echo Server that returns the message sent to it back.
I am having an issue obtaining data from a char array after it is received from TCP.

This is how the char array is defined.

```
#define RCVBUFSZ 50

char *rcvBuffer[RCVBUFSZ];
```

when I call

```
bytesRead = recv(sock, rcvBuffer, RCVBUFSZ - 1, 0)
```

my rcvBuffer should be full of 49 chars saving the last spot for a null terminator however...

if I

```
printf("%s", rcvBuffer)
```

it prints out the message I want to see at the beginning then followed by nonsense.

Then if I try printing with a for loop i get every 4th character of my message.

```
for (i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
{
    printf("%c", rcvBuffer[i]);
}
```

Why does my char array allocate enough memory for 200 characters when I specified 50?
How do I print data from my buffer and stop when it turns to gibberish?

Comment: 'my rcvBuffer should be full of 49 chars' ... no.  Anywhere between 0 and 49 chars may have been loaded into the buffer.  'bytesRead', if not negative, tells you how many.  Zero has a special meaning too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char *rcvBuffer[RCVBUFSZ];` is not an array of `char`it is an array of `char*` (array of 50 pointers to `char`). Change it to `char rcvBuffer[RCVBUFSZ];`. Apart from this you should ensure that your string is terminated by `'\0'`:

```
char rcvBuffer[RCVBUFSZ];
int bytesRead = recv( sock, rcvBuffer, RCVBUFSZ - 1, 0 );
rcvBuffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
char *rcvBuffer[RCVBUFSZ];
```

does allocate space for a `RCVBUFSZ` number of pointers to `char`. If the pointer size is 4 bytes, then you are allocating memory of 50*4=200 bytes. 
But according to your description, you want to allocate memory for an array of `RCVBUFSZ` chars. Thus, you must change the code to:

```
char rcvBuffer[RCVBUFSZ];  // no '*' after char
```

You must also NUL-terminate the string before passing it to `printf("%s", rcvBuffer)`. Thus add

```
rcvBuffer[bytesRead] = 0;
```

after the `recv` call.